# perl IO eventhandler for untainting strings

Tags: perl, taint-checking

How do I create an event handler in my Perl code to intercept all File/Directory/system-based calls, so that I can untaint input in a just-in-time fashion.

I have lots of IO access in my script, and I find adding manual code for untainting cumbersome.

Can this be done without need to install a third-party CPAN module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try taking an [aspect-oriented approach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) but it does require installing a CPAN module, [Aspect](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/Aspect-0.43/lib/Aspect.pm).

To capture calls to a particular method / function, you define a pointcut (taken from the Aspect POD):

```
$pointcut = call qr/^Person::[gs]et_/; # defines a collection of events
```

Then define the code to take before the call:

```
$before = before {
  print "g/set will soon be called";
} $pointcut;
```

Although I'm not sure if the Aspect module allows you to trap calls to the CORE::* namespace.

Answer (score 1):

How do expect to untaint general data? If you're just going to blindly accept everything despite its source, there's no point in using taint-checking.

You might want to read the "Secure Programming Techniques" chapter in [Mastering Perl](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596527242). I give quite a bit of advice for dealing with this sort of stuff. However, any good advice is going to be targeted at specific situations, not generalizations.

Comment: I can run it through a series of regular expressions and branches(if/else/case) etc.

Comment: That puts you back where you started though.